# Gluon/JavaFXPorts automated UI tests

Tags: android, coded-ui-tests, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

Is there any way to have automated UI testing in Apps created with Gluon-Mobile.
E.g does Espresso for Android work with Gluon?
I wouldn't think so since Espresso takes ElementIds but is there any way to work around this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since applications written with Gluon Mobile are a fairly standard JavaFX applications you can try one of JavaFX testing frameworks. I would recomment to start with [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX) framework

Comment: I know that you can test the standard javafx application on desktop. But I am looking for something to test it on Android and iOS.

Comment: Even though I haven't tried... I would imagine the TestFX to be a normal Java app. That means it can be compiled down to iOS and Android

Comment: Okay I'll take back my comment :D Thank you very much I'll look into it and as soon as I have running code I'll accept your answer (which might take a while)